# Searching an object (by an attribute) in a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I need to get a better way to find an object in a NSMutableArray.

At the moment i do it this way:

```
for(classOfTheObject *thisItem in arrayOfObjects){
    if(thisItem.foreign_key == serchThisObject.foreign_key){
        // found it
    }
}
```

but this is a very bad way i think. Is it possible to get the object without a for loop?

Comment: What type is the object?

Comment: You can create NSDictionary and add your object for its name as a key.

Comment: Why do you think a for loop is bad?

Comment: I thought the for loop takes to much time. I will try to use an NSDictionary, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an array it will always require some type of loop/enumaration to actually find it. If `foreign_key` is the only search/identification criteria that you use then you may consider using an `NSDictionary` with the value of `foreign_key` as key.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you,I would use NSPredicate :

```
NSPredicate *applePred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                  @"employer.name == 'Apple'"];
NSArray *appleEmployees = [people filteredArrayUsingPredicate:applePred];
```